# How do you get a doubleValue to get an output?

Tags: java

I am working on this project for class, but can't seem to get an answer to the equation.

**What I want -**

Enter the A value for the line: 2.45

Enter the B value for the line: 4

Enter the C value for the line: -8

Enter the x coordinate of the point: 2.17

Enter the y coordinate of the point: -4

Distance from the point to the line is: 3.9831092774319026

**What I am getting -** Distance from the point to the line is: NaN

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DistToline {
public static double A;
public static double B;
public static double C;
public static double distance;

public static double
getDist(double a, double b){
    distance= Math.abs(((A*a)+(B*b)+(C))/(Math.pow(A, 2))+(Math.pow(B, 2)));
    return distance;
 }


 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    Scanner f= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the A value for the line:");
    Double A = f.nextDouble();

    Scanner g= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the B value for the line:");
    Double B = g.nextDouble();

    Scanner h= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the C value for the line:");
    Double C = h.nextDouble();

    Scanner i= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the x coordinate of the point:");
    Double X = i.nextDouble();

    Scanner j= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the y coordinate of the point:");
    Double Y = j.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Distance from the point to the line is: ");
    System.out.println(getDist(5,4));

 }
}
```

From what I think I am doing wrong is that I am not doing the calculations and am not returning the distance as a double is this why I am not getting an output? If so how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

```
Double A = f.nextDouble();
```

This does not assign the value to the member

```
public static double A;
```

it creates a local variable called A.

Change to

```
A = f.nextDouble();
```

And repeat for all those other member variables.

Comment: Also using `this.A` etc. is a good practice to see if you are changing the properties of the object and not a random variable that is not tied to the object.

Comment: You cannot use this.A in this case as A is a static member not an instance member. The this keyword only applies to instances. You could use DistToline.A instead of this.A

Comment: Did not notice static. Why would he use static anyways its better to use non static.

Comment: Probably because he is new to java. New java users find that in order to access variables from their static main method they need to make the variables static as well. Instead of creating an instance of a class they just make everything static. I expect it is because Classes are not covered in lecture 1.

Answer (score 0):

For variables A,B,C ,you already declare static and again in main method,you are again declare variables as double thats why value for A & B becomes zero and NaN appears.Below is your running code with minor changes-

```
public class DistToline {
public static double A;
public static double B;
public static double C;
public static double distance;

public static double
getDist(double a, double b){
    distance= Math.abs(((A*a)+(B*b)+(C))/(Math.pow(A, 2))+(Math.pow(B, 2)));
    return distance;
 }



public static void main(String args[])
{
   Scanner f= new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the A value for the line:");
    A = f.nextDouble();

   Scanner g= new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the B value for the line:");
    B = g.nextDouble();

   Scanner h= new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the C value for the line:");
    C = h.nextDouble();

   Scanner i= new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the x coordinate of the point:");
   Double X = i.nextDouble();

   Scanner j= new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter the y coordinate of the point:");
   Double Y = j.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("Distance from the point to the line is: ");
   System.out.println(getDist(5,4));

}
```